# PHP script connecting TCP/IP server?

Tags: php, networking

I know that PHP does allow you to create a server but what about client? I would need a script that connects to my TCP/IP server on given port and send some data. Is that possible in PHP and if so, could you help me please? I did not find anything useful.
I have my TCP/IP server running on port 1301 and I would need users to be able by clicking on web page send one char to the server.

Comment: You can use the CURL library. Also sockets directly. Can you expand your question?

Comment: read the stream functions in the php manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to how you would create a server. I'd recommend taking a look at the documentation for [socket_connect](http://php.net/socket_connect).

Summaries:

- [socket_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php)
- [socket_bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php)
- [socket_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php)
- [socket_write](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php)
- [socket_read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php)
- [socket_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-close.php)

Workflow:

- Create the socket
- Optionally bind it
- Connect to the server
- Read/write data
- Close the socket

Comment: As a general resource for sockets, more tailored to C than PHP, but helpful nonetheless: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Answer (score 2):

I've used this piece before. It's fairly simple; it connects to $ip_address on port $port, and sends the $sendData data to the server, and then reads the response and returns the response.

```
$sendData = chr(6).chr(0).chr(255).chr(255).'info';
function sendAndGetResponse($ip_address, $port, $sendData){
$socketHandler=@fsockopen($ip_address, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
if(!$socketHandler)
{
    return false; //offline
}
else
{
    $response = '';
    stream_set_timeout($socketHandler, 2);
    fwrite($socketHandler, $sendData);
    while (!feof($socketHandler))
    {
        stream_set_timeout($socketHandler, 2);
        $response .= fgets($socketHandler, 1024);
    }
    fclose($socketHandler);
    return $response;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CURL if it is HTTP server or create a socket connection http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php

Answer (score -3):

Yes, php can act as a HTTP-client with CURL, fsockopen and most easiest way to fetch URL - with `file_get_contents()`

Comment: That's not TCP/IP, that's HTTP

Comment: using file_get_contents doesn't offer connection persistence

Comment: I know. But if developer doesn't know that php can as a client, then i doubt that he actually needs SSL or NetBios. And HTTP is most used.

Comment: "I would need a script that connects to my **TCP/IP server**"

Comment: HTTP **IS** TCP/IP . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol . "HTTP is an Application Layer protocol designed within the framework of the Internet Protocol Suite. The protocol definitions presume a reliable Transport Layer protocol for host-to-host data transfer.[2] The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) is the dominant protocol in use for this purpose."

Comment: HTTP *works on* TCP/IP, but *is* is not the correct word here.

Comment: As you can see from latest edit of the question.. it is correct. Because he actually needs interaction with a web page. So no, its not a custom server

Comment: No, he says he want to send *one char* to a TCP/IP (assuming he means TCP) server *when* a user clicks on a webpage. Read more carefully :)

Comment: No, he says **need users to be able by clicking on web page** which doesnt involve serverside.. I doubt that he means making a request with javascript/flash/applet that doesn't involve HTTP.

Comment: @Artjom, I'm not sure you understand.  HTTP would be needed to fetch the webpage that the user will click on, but that is not the question.  You ***don't*** need HTTP for the request from the webpage (client) to the TCP/IP server.

Comment: @jedwards well since he accepted sockets-answer then you are right and it is serverside request with pure TCP/IP. A good lesson not to assume  information thats not provided